# Plotting a two variable function in the form of list using Python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, arraylist, plot

I have a list f containing (N-1)*(N-1) variables which stores the values at each grid (x[i], y[i]). x and y are defined as lists storing the x and y coordinates of grid: which looks like x=[h, 2*h, ..., (N-1)*h] and y=[h, 2*h, ..., (N-1)*h] where h is constant spacing between the points.

The function values of f is defined using the elements of x and y: f[k]=f[i+j*(N-1)] where i and j are the index from x and y. Specifically, f=[g(x[0],y[0]), g(x[1],y[0]),...,g(x[N-2],y[N-2])], where g is a 2-variable function which depends on the values x[i] and y[j].

What I want to do is plotting the values g(x[i],y[j]) on the 2-D grid in the contour format. Since the list I have is 1-D, I could not figure out what function of matplotlib I must use.

Can somebody recommend me a good way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at scipy [interpolate.griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) function, I think it may do what you need.

Comment: If you want a complete answer here then you should try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).